# How to add shadow for context menu in JavaFX?

Tags: css, javafx-2, shadow

How to add shadow for context menu in JavaFX? I've searched it in stackoverflow, apparently, nobody else asked this question.
Like click on menu in menubar, there will be a context menu (or popup menu) dropped down. I want this to have a drop shadow as the list view does in combo box.
All that I mentioned is in JavaFX 2.2, and I want preferably to do this drop shadow in CSS.
Thanks~~